# Google Play Store Internal testing temporary app name

Tags: android, google-play

I released today a version to the Internal Testing in Google Play, but i notice two things.

[image]
[image]

The *Temporary app name* and the *Not reviewed*. I thought app reviewing by Google was not a necessary step during Internal Testing.

So i have some questions:

1 - Is my app under Google Review right now? Does it will change from *Not reviewed* to *Pending* or something else?

2 - If it is not under review, how do i apply to review only for my internal testing? When the temporary name will change to the correct one?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So from just sending something for Internal Test just now I believe the answer to 1) is no your app is not under review now. This will only happen when you sumbit an app to Production. Your Internal Test app is available now for you to download in the usual way.

As for 2) I think the answer is you can't or you don't, reviews are only conducted when promoted to Production or a new release is added to Production.

When the temporary name will change to the correct one? I don't 100% know that one because I have an app that will always be called something stupid because it will never go into Production (and I have not got to that post review stage), but I believe that once you pass the Production review your app will be renamed to what you intended it to be.

Update 16-Feb-2021: OK so I was incorrect, the name does not stay as the temporary name until you release, you need to submit all the information for release and then wait a bit. In my case I created an app that will never move from Internal Test and completed all the tasks to get it to release and it was still showing the temporary name. Now I look back at the app and it's the correct name, so there's some process that changes it and it's not immediate.

Comment: How long that took for you? I've finished all app set-up 5 days ago and internal testing link doesn't work and app keeps the temporary name.

Comment: @FellipeLima Well from looking at the dates from the post and my update 6 days, but I would hardly call that scientific. I didn't find any documentation on it either. The testing link should work though, it just takes you to the app with the temporary name.

Comment: @FellipeLima, less than 1 day.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. Forgot to share what happened. The app only became with official name and went through review after moving to closed testing. Didn't make any sense as I wanted to keep it internal only, but after that it got all resolved within 4hrs.

Comment: If the app is `unreviewed`, then how does it get published on a track?

Comment: My experience has been similar. Our app was approved for production and I manually published it over 12 hours ago. The app is not yet visible on the Play store and it still shows "Not reviewed" in the console, despite having been approved and released. I imagine this will correct itself in the next day or two.

Answer (score 9):

Basically, after filling up the details like, Store Listing, App Content, Privacy Policy etc, the app will be sent for review to Google automatically only if you are doing any one of the followings:

1. Closed Test (Alpha Release)
2. Open Test (Beta Release)
3. Public Release (Play Store public listing)

However, if you are doing just an internal release or Pre-Registration those will not be reviewed by Google and you cannot send also manually for review.

Comment: Once my Closed Test passes Google review, will my Internal Test URL that I send to anonymous users show my app icon & screenshots?

Comment: Yes it will show